# Add description to Facebook LIKE button

Tags: facebook

I want to add more information on my wall about liked items; right now there is just commment, and a liked URL.

Information I want to add are item description, item title, item picture, etc.

It is for my iframe application where I get data with JSON, so I want use that information to be shown when someone liked any item.

I used meta tags, but there is no difference at all; sometimes I get "Sample Property" for item title, and "Some Arbitrary String" as item description, even if put some different content in meta tags.

Comment: after editing the meta tags, try to check your og tags with the facebook linter. fb caches your meta tags, by running the debugger the cache is refreshed.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to customize the data published on user's wall/feed/timeline is to define correct [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me) meta tags (like `og:title`, `og:image`, `og:description`, etc).

The data in OpenGraph tags are cached by Facebook so to purge the cache and fetch fresh data you need to use [Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Use it to check if errors exist (and fix em if any) and to ensure if the details are correct.

Comment: I definitely looked over that invaluable Debug Tool; I did not see that in the same documentation.